# A request to refer to the bottom of the document

Tags: phrase-request

I have created a table in a "Word" document and described each column of it. Description came out to be too big, so I decided to move it down to the very end  of the document. But I want the users to know that the description is still there in the document. What would be the most acceptable way to notify them?

I tried this:

> 1. (go to the bottom of this document, to see the description of each column)

Does it sound a bit rude?

Should it be like:

> 2. (please, go to the bottom of this document, to see the description of each column)

Or, perhaps, this would be better:

> 3. (for the description of each column, refer to the bottom of this document)

None of these three sits right with me. What would you write in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the most acceptable way to notify them?

I am assuming you are writing this message in the footnote. I would write

> "See page 30 for ..."

or

> "See Annex I for ..."

You can use the term "appendix" too.

Note that in 1 and 2, the comma after "document" makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, but what if it's not an annex and I am not sure about the precise number of the last page? Could I write something like "See the end of this document for..."?

Comment: You can insert page numbers in all word processors. I think "end" is better than "bottom", but it is still something that I would avoid.

Comment: "See below" seems like an idiomatic choice here, although it doesn't specifically mean "end."